# Первая и последняя страница - Yii2 пагинация (GridView)

Tags: php, yii2, gridview, pagination

На страницах выводятся таблицы через GridView::widget, чтобы всем не прописывать

```
'pager' => [
        'firstPageLabel' => 'First',
        'lastPageLabel' => 'Last',
],
```

хочу это как-то автоматизировать.
Нашел метод getLinks в Pagination.php, там как раз написано походу то что нужно

```
public function getLinks($absolute = false)
{
    $currentPage = $this->getPage();
    $pageCount = $this->getPageCount();
    $links = [
        Link::REL_SELF => $this->createUrl($currentPage, null, $absolute),
    ];
    if ($currentPage > 0) {
        $links[self::LINK_FIRST] = $this->createUrl(0, null, $absolute);
        $links[self::LINK_PREV] = $this->createUrl($currentPage - 1, null, $absolute);
    }
    if ($currentPage < $pageCount - 1) {
        $links[self::LINK_NEXT] = $this->createUrl($currentPage + 1, null, $absolute);
        $links[self::LINK_LAST] = $this->createUrl($pageCount - 1, null, $absolute);
    }

    return $links;
}
```

Но как и где правильно вызвать данный метод?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если используете **GridView**, то так:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'pager' => [
        'firstPageLabel' => 'Первая страница',
        'lastPageLabel'  => 'Последняя страница'
    ],
    ...
]) ?>
```

Если используете пагинацию при помощи виджета **LinkPager**, то так:

```
<?= yii\widgets\LinkPager::widget([
     //все остальное
     'firstPageLabel' => 'Первая',
     'lastPageLabel' => 'Последняя'
]);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте свой `MyPager`, занеследуйтесь от дефолтного, настройте там все, что вам нужно. И во всяких `GridView` указывайте свой класс `MyPager`.